# How to unlock (not buy) a TRUCK, 1/4 TON, 4X4 in Heroes and Generals

Tags: heroes-and-generals

I can't seem to drive this vehicle when it is locked. I have tried holding E when i am by the driver's door but i just go into the gunner seat.

Answer (score 1):

It must be "owned" by someone on your team already. I believe if they die then you'd be able to unlock it. I assume it is set up this way so teammates don't accidentally steal each others vehicles when they run into control points.